# Resolving warning for Micronaut and Gradle 5 "Detecting annotation processors on the compile classpath is deprecated" warning

Tags: gradle, groovy, deprecation-warning, micronaut

I am attempting to resolve the warning below from Gradle.  It only occurs when I invoke testing code.  The main Java (only) run and build tasks work fine.

The testing code is in Groovy.  It seems that Groovy in combination with Gradle and Micronaut raise this message on projects where the message was resolved weeks back but stubbornly persists on the `test` and `testCompile` related tasks.

```
> Task :plumbing:compileTestGroovy
The following annotation processors were detected on the compile classpath: 
'io.micronaut.annotation.processing.TypeElementVisitorProcessor' and     'io.micronaut.annotation.processing.PackageConfigurationInjectProcessor' and
'io.micronaut.annotation.processing.BeanDefinitionInjectProcessor'.
 Detecting annotation processors on the compile classpath is
 deprecated and Gradle 5.0 will ignore them. Please add them
 to the annotation processor path instead. If you did not 
intend to use annotation processors, you can use the 
'-proc:none' compiler argument to ignore them.
```

By starting with Micronaut the instructions to work with Lombok I found through trial-and-error that so far the only way for my Groovy tests to run is to use the following recipe in the `build.gradle` file.  The Micronaut recipe specifies to put Lombok before Micronaut.  Which is effective for Java builds.

In order to have Groovy code compile and then execute I'm (seemingly) required to write my dependencies as so:

```
configurations {
    annotationProcessor
}

dependencies
{
    compileOnly (
        dep_lombok                  //  Must come first
    )

    annotationProcessor (
        dep_lombokAtnProc,          //  Must come first
        dep_micronautAtnProc
    )

    compileOnly (
        dep_micronaut              //  Must follow annotationProcessor 
    )

    implementation (
        project( ':base'),
    )

    testImplementation (
        project( ':TestingSupport')
    )

    testImplementation (
        dep_micronaut,
        dep_commonsConfig
    )
}
```

- The dependencies `dep_XXX` are just strings.
- The "`AtnProc...`" label is to specifically identify the Annotation Processor (even when it is the same coordinate).

If the `compileOnly ( dep micronaut )` clause it necessary for things like `@Inject` to be processed with the Groovy builds. And ...

- It must be in the order shown, following the `annotationProcessor(..)` clause.

Despite the situation that there are no annotations in the Groovy files at this point anyway.

With the above build information, the Groovy specificaitons run and work correctly.  However I still get the `Deprecated ...` warning.

Without the `compileOnly( Micronaut )` phrase I get compile errors and nothing runs.  `testCompileOnly`, a `groovyCompileOnly` or `testAnnotationProcessor` do nothing.

Who knows how to build and run Groovy tests with Gradle when using Micronaut?  Tests coexist with Lombok fine.

The things missing are `@Inject`, `@Singleton`, etc.

Looking forward to suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the warning was resolved for your main module once adding the `annotationProcessor` configuration but continues for your test module, would lead me to believe that annotation processors are being used in your test code.

Similarly to the [`kapt` Kotlin annotation processor](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#kotlin) plugin, I believe that you need to configure your annotation processors for your test module with `testAnnocationProcessor` as below:

```
    testAnnotationProcessor (
        dep_lombokAtnProc,
        dep_micronautAtnProc
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, that is an idea to follow-up.  I believed that `test` "inherited" anything from the compile and runtime build specifications.  If this works, then that would indicate that this isn't so after all.  Hmmm?